# why i can use set to change private member,but can't use =

Tags: java

here i have some doubts about why we can use setter to change a private member but can't use "=" to change it.
for example

```
public class Student {
    private Date date;
    private Integer age;
    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}

public class HelloTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student student = new Student();
        student.getDate().setTime(1000);
        //student.getAge()=100;  not allowed
    }
}
```

I don't know why I can use '.setTime(1000)' to change Date, but can't use '=100' to change age.
In my mind, both getDate and getAge get the object reference.
Thanks.

Comment: That's not how functions work... Just because it returns a value doesn't mean you can treat the function as if it were a local variable.

Comment: Apart from your question, you should probably be using Calendar for your dates.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example you are returning an Object then calling a method on that Object to change its value (not a new Object)

In the second example you are returning an `immutable` object and then trying to autobox to change its Object

Comment: yeah, it's a question about immutable, but i wonder why the first is mutable, the second is not

Comment: `Integer` is an immutable Object.  `Date` is mutable

Comment: @L.Tian it's by design of creators of these classes. No magic at all. The `Integer` class is called "immutable" just because it hasn't any methods (like `setValue` or something) which can mutate its internal state. The `Date` has such methods. By the way the new datetime api in `Java 8` also uses immutable classes.

Answer (score 0):

Any `set...` or `get...` method is a function inside the class, such as `setAge`, `getDate`, and `setDate` in your example. In order to directly change a class variable from outside the class, you need to make it `public`. There are reasons to not do this, and use setters/getters, but in some instances it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `=` because your `getAge` method is returning a reference to an object. References, just like literals and other values, can be assigned to variables of the proper type. Your code doesn't work because it's like trying to write `10 = 100;` which makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, not an object.

> In my mind, both getDate and getAge get the object reference.

Yes, they do. Not a reference to the variable.

To make it clear, you'd better consider that they return an anonymous variable refering to the object.

At first, let's assume the field variable `age` refers to an object. (It's null at the OP's example, but the same story can be applied.)

[image]

When you call `getAge()`, it returns an anonymous variable that refers to the object.

[image]

The assignment operator means "let the left-hand side variable refer to the object that the right-hand side expression refers to". So if your `student.getAge()=100` were allowed, it would result in the following situation.

[image]

Of course this is meaningless, so Java doesn't allow that at compile-time.

On the other hand, your first example `.setTime(1000)` is not an assignment, so it works fine.